# Looking to draw line between two dynamically selected points in mapkit

Tags: ios5, mapkit, cllocationmanager, cllocation, cllocationdistance

I am working on an app that would draw a "route" between two points on a lake that will be dynamically selected from annotations on the map. I've looked to see if anyone has tried to do this, and I haven't found an answer to this question.  If you can help that would be great.

Comment: It is a pretty basic situation where you have an array of cllotations and you draw a line joining these locations. Check other question regarding MKPolyline and MKPolyLineView.

Comment: Except that they are dynamic annotations on a map and I want to get the distance and heading between those two points.  I know it's probably something simple.  Thanks.

Comment: An MKAnnotation has a set of coordinates. Create CLLocations based on these coordinates, rinse, repeat. Getting the distance will be as easy as distanceFromLocation: and for heading you need to do a little bit of trigonometry (not strictly related to map kit).

Comment: Being new to ipad and iphone development, I'm confused on distanceFromLocation.  If you could give me a code sample that would be great.  Thanks.